# Inline images in a TextView

Tags: java, android, html

I'm trying to put inline images in a TextView. Here goes my code:

```
ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() {
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        Drawable d = ctx.getResources().getDrawable(Integer.parseInt(source));
        d.setBounds(0, 0, d.getIntrinsicWidth(), d.getIntrinsicHeight());
        return d;
    }
};
CharSequence votesString="124 votes";
votesString=Html.fromHtml(votesString
           +"(<img src='" + R.drawable.icon_upvotes + "'/>)", imageGetter, null);
labelVotes.setText(votesString);
```

It works (see the image below) but I would need the image to be vertically centered. How can I do that?

[image]

Thanks

Comment: did u tried layout center in xml?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of use HTML, you can use

```
labelVotes.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, 0, R.drawable.icon_upvotes);
```

and playing a little bit with padding, using `setCompoundDrawablePadding`

Answer (score 1):

Why you don't use [android:drawableRight](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#attr_android%3adrawableRight) ?